# Form in html not getting redirected to PHP file

Tags: php, html, css, forms, post

I am creating a simple HTML website using bootstrap and CSS and am using PHP for form handling. I am using the POST method to submit the values of the form to a PHP file where I am trying to receive the values and printing them. However, when I press the submit button on the form, the HTML page is not getting redirected to the PHP file that is in the action element of the form. It just gets stuck on the HTML page. Please take a look at the below code and help me figure out why the values of the form are not getting submitted into the PHP file.

This is the code for the form in the HTML file:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="contact-form">
      <form action="contact.php" method="post" id="contact-form" role="form">
        <fieldset>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="fullname" class="form-control" id="full-name" placeholder="Full Name*" data-error="Full name is required" required>
              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email Address*" data-error="Email is required" required>
              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone number" id="phone" data-error="Phone number is required" required>
              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject*" name="subject" id="subject" data-error="Subject is required" required>
              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea cols="40" rows="10" name="message" class="textarea form-control" placeholder="Your Message" id="message" data-error="Message is required" required></textarea>
              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <button class="btn-send" type="submit" name="submit">Send</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class='form-response'></div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The contact.php file looks something like this:

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
  $fullName = $_POST['fullname'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  echo 'Your name is ' . $fullName .' and your email ID is' . $email;
}
?>
```

I have been unable to figure out exactly what the problem is. Please take look at this code and help me figure this problem out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Press F12 and look in the network tab. Also never call anything in a form `name="submit"` if you ever plan on submitting it using script. Do you perhaps have a form plugin? The form works as it stands here

Comment: Why do you not use name="submit"? I don't think I am using a form plugin. It is just HTML. After checking in the network tab I found that I am getting the following error: Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. `The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.` @mplungjan

Comment: name=submit will hide the submit event/method of the form. `The requested URL was not found on this server` seems to tell you all. Your php is not where you think it is if you get a 404

Comment: I checked after I click the submit button it is not looking for my "contact.php" file, instead, it is searching for some strange php file that doesn't exist and its directory is `http://localhost:8080/php/form-process.php`. I don't understand why.

Comment: That is indeed weird.

Answer (score 1):

It should work. Have you made sure that the contact.php file is in the same folder as this html page?

Comment: This should be a comment please not an answer

Answer (score 1):

put php code in same file.
use this html

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="contact-form">
      <form action="" method="post">
        <fieldset>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="fullname" class="form-control" id="full-name" placeholder="Full Name*" data-error="Full name is required" required>
              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email Address*" data-error="Email is required" required>
              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone number" id="phone" data-error="Phone number is required" required>
              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject*" name="subject" id="subject" data-error="Subject is required" required>
              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea cols="40" rows="10" name="message" class="textarea form-control" placeholder="Your Message" id="message" data-error="Message is required" required></textarea>
              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <button class="btn-send" type="submit" name="submit">Send</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class='form-response'></div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> 

Comment: i did modify try again

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly working. Make sure your folders are in right place
(eg : in wamp your folders must be inside www folder). And make sure your server is running.